# Entity Framework, Error when deleting data from multiple tables at the same time

Tags: c#, entity-framework

```
using (TransactionScope scope = new TransactionScope())
{
    var ListTumu1 = entities.tapubilgileri.Where(p => p.kullaniciadi == KullaniciAdiKullanici && p.raporadi == RaporAdiKullanici).ToList();
    var ListTumu2 = entities.imardurumubilgileri.Where(p => p.kullaniciadi == KullaniciAdiKullanici && p.raporadi == RaporAdiKullanici).ToList();
    var ListTumu3 = entities.yapibilgileri.Where(p => p.kullaniciadi == KullaniciAdiKullanici && p.raporadi == RaporAdiKullanici).ToList();
    var ListTumu4 = entities.sondajbilgileri.Where(p => p.kullaniciadi == KullaniciAdiKullanici && p.raporadi == RaporAdiKullanici).ToList();
    var ListTumu5 = entities.sismikbilgileri.Where(p => p.kullaniciadi == KullaniciAdiKullanici && p.raporadi == RaporAdiKullanici).ToList();
    var ListTumu6 = entities.arastirmacukurubilgileri.Where(p => p.kullaniciadi == KullaniciAdiKullanici && p.raporadi == RaporAdiKullanici).ToList();
    var ListTumu7 = entities.rezistivitebilgileri.Where(p => p.kullaniciadi == KullaniciAdiKullanici && p.raporadi == RaporAdiKullanici).ToList();
    var ListTumu8 = entities.microtremorbilgileri.Where(p => p.kullaniciadi == KullaniciAdiKullanici && p.raporadi == RaporAdiKullanici).ToList();
    ///...
    ///...
    ///...

    entities.tapubilgileri.RemoveRange(ListTumu1);
    entities.imardurumubilgileri.RemoveRange(ListTumu2);
    entities.yapibilgileri.RemoveRange(ListTumu3);
    entities.sondajbilgileri.RemoveRange(ListTumu4);
    entities.sismikbilgileri.RemoveRange(ListTumu5);
    entities.arastirmacukurubilgileri.RemoveRange(ListTumu6);
    entities.rezistivitebilgileri.RemoveRange(ListTumu7);
    entities.microtremorbilgileri.RemoveRange(ListTumu8);
    ///...
    ///...

    try
    {
        entities.SaveChanges();

        scope.Complete();
        acceptStatus = true;
    }
    catch (System.Exception ex)  //Exception kontrolü yapmamızda yarar var 
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Sorun var!");
    }
}

if (acceptStatus)
{
    // Db.AcceptAllChanges();
}
```

Entity Framework, I am trying to delete data from multiple tables at the same time with the code below, but after a while, I get an error

> The underlying provider failed on Open

I wonder what is the reason for this error?

Also, deleting data this way is very slow. SQL login is performed for each table. Is there a faster way to do this?

Comment: Please add a tag for the exact EF version you're using. In EFC 7 and higher you could benefit from the `ExecuteDelete` method. Side note: do yourself a favor and use CamelCase for property (and class) names and (probably) just remove this "gileri" suffix.

Comment: As you say, I am using EntityFramework 6.4.4, will switching to version 7 solve the problem? and there is no direct update for version 7 in visual studio. How can I update without losing data and structures? Thank you for your other suggestions, I will implement the corrections in the future, but for now this issue is more important.

Comment: The step from EF6 to EF-core is not a question of just updating. EF-core is very different. For now, if I were you, I'd resort to raw SQL statements. It's too much of a roundabout way to load entities first only to delete them. I think the context's cache can't handle it, *possibly* leading to that exception.